# Weierstrass points on a general curve are distinct

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Are the Weierstrass points of a general genus $g$ curve all of weight 1?

If we instead took a fixed curve and a general $g^r_d$ (divisor of degree $d$ with $r+1$ sections) are the ramification points all weight 1?

Comment: For your second question I have a few questions to ask to clarify what you ask. You ask about a fixed curve. Do you really mean any fixed curve or are you still thinking of a general curve? Sometimes there may be only finitely many $g_d^r$'s. What is a general $g_d^r$ in that case?

Comment: I think anything that can yield an interesting answer. If I knew enough to pare this question down to something specific, I would have asked this on MO. I think Harris and Eisenbud have results showing the existence of lots of ramification sequences for Weierstrass points on curves, but I have no idea what the ramification sequences are supposed to look like in general. A naive guess would be that they should all have weight one, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: With regards to your first question, all Weierstrass points on a general are distinct, yes. For a proof, see "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris, page 277.